# Source of faulty reasoning in expectation of product of random variables?

Tags: random-variables, expectation, products

For iid $\xi_i>0$, with $\mathbb E[\xi_i]=1$, what is $\mathbb E[\prod_i^M\xi_i]$?

**Approach 1**: $\mathbb E[\prod_i^M\xi_i]=\prod_i^M\mathbb E[\xi_i]=1$.

There is another approach for $M\gg1$ with presumably faulty reasoning that gives a different result:

**Approach 2:** $\mathbb E[\prod_i^M\xi_i]=\mathbb E[\exp(\sum_i^M\log(\xi_i)]\approx \mathbb E[\exp(M\mathbb E[\log(\xi_i)])]=\exp(M\mathbb E[\log(\xi_i)])$. 
Take any of the many distributions of the $\xi_i$ where the expectation and the logarithm do not commute so that $\mathbb E[\log(\xi_i)]$ is some finite number. Then $\mathbb E[\prod_i^M\xi_i]\neq 1$.

Where is the faulty reasoning? (n.b. It could be something pretty basic. I am no expert.)

Additional notes: Regarding Approach 2, Central limit theorem arguments imply that $X_M=\prod_i^M\xi_i$ is log-normally distributed for $M\gg1$ so that $\mathbb E[X_M]=\exp(\mu +\sigma^2/2)$, where $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are the mean and variance of $\log X_M=\sum_i^M \log\xi_i$. Since the variance of the normal distribution in logspace will grow with $M$ so will the mean of $E[X_M]$. Again it does not seem to equal 1 in this line of reasoning.

Thanks!

**Edit:** Angela answered that this is a convergence issue. Let's look at a convergent case then: $X_i=(\prod_i^M\xi_i)^\frac{1}{M}$.

Now, it is not clear that **Approach 1** can be carried out.

**Approach 2** now seems to go through: $\mathbb E[(\prod_i^M\xi_i)^\frac{1}{M}]=\mathbb E[\exp(\frac{1}{M}\sum_i^M\log(\xi_i)]\approx \mathbb E[\exp(\mathbb E[\log(\xi_i)])]=\exp(\mathbb E[\log(\xi_i)])$.

As an example, if $\xi_i$ is gamma-distributed with unit-valued scale parameter and shape parameter $k$, $E[\log(\xi_i)]=\psi(k)$, where $\psi(k)$ is the digamma function.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the step $\mathbb{E}[\exp \sum_{i=1}^M \log \xi_i]\approx \mathbb{E}[\exp M\mathbb{E}[\log\xi_i]]$.

As $M\rightarrow \infty$ the left and right hand sides of the approximate equality do not converge to each other except in the special case where the expectation and logarithm commute.

Comment: Thanks! Even before that step, for finite $M$, the suggested result from the reasoning in the additional note in the OP seems to indicate that the result is not equal to 1. Does one also need convergence for CLT arguments? I thought that they approximately hold so long as $M$ is large enough and that the moments of $\xi_i$ are finite. Any ideas on this?